# How to get order collection filter with customer_is_guest and email (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, sales-order, guest-checkout, order-collection

How to get order id from collection with filter `customer_is_guest = 1` and `customer email`

```
$order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email)->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest',1);
```

Above code will give me `order collection`. How to only get order id/ids

Comment: Try 
$order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => NULL))

For guest customer you need to check customer_id is NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can use addFieldToSelect() function in your collection as follows:

```
$order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> To get guest user orders by specific email

```
<?php                                                                 
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Orders;                               
 class ReadOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory) {
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', 'prathap@gmail.com')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', '1');
    foreach ($orders as $items) {
        echo $items->getEntityId() . '<pre>';
    }
}}
```

> It will print the increment id of the above order collection filter.

Hope this helps.
Peace :)